# How to pass ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am using SQL Server 2008 and C# ADO.NET to accomplish this.

I want to use stored procedure to insert these data into table `SAVEDATA`

Thank you

Srosh

Comment: how did I get a negative without even asking a question is it not clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just write an `INSERT` statement and you select the data from that table that's being passed in:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSave] (@theDATA As [dbo].[TVP] Readonly)
AS
BEGIN      
    INSERT INTO dbo.SaveResponse(ID, myQuestion, PersonWhoResponses,
                                 Response, [User], [DateTime])

       SELECT 
          ID, myQuestion, PersonWhoResponses,
          Response, [User], [DateTime]
       FROM
          @theDATA
END
```

Comment: BTW: using `User` and `DateTime` as column names is **horribly bad design** - those are reserved words - **don't use them yourself as column or table names!**.

Comment: Marc, I will change the names now, thanks for suggestion, and how would you suggest I could code this in my ADO.NET side C#? How should create my table with varying data lengths?  any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @SroshSharar: on the ADO.NET side, you need to create a `DataTable` that contains the correct number of `DataColumns` (that match the definition of your table type) and then you need to fill that `DataTable` with data and pass it to the stored procedure

Comment: Marc, I have another table called User. If I want to get the User name from column USERNAME based on the ID in this table, how would I do that?

Comment: I solved it myself. Thanks a lot though for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO @theData ( 
  SELECT [ID], [myQuestion], [PersonWhoResponses], [Response] , [User],  [DateTime]
  FROM SAVERESPONSE
  WHERE ...
)
```

Comment: `@theDATA` is an **input** parameter into the stored procedure - and it's marked as `READONLY` - you **CANNOT** add data rows into that variable! You need to **read them from that variable** instead.

Comment: I agree too, sorry for my mistake

Comment: Maybe you could help with this Norbert, I have another table called User. If I want to get the User name from column USERNAME based on the ID in this table, how would I do that?

Comment: it is simple WHERE. On query like SELECT * FROM <table> You can use WHERE to get filtered records. In thix example it would be : SELECT [USERNAME] FROM dbo.[User] WHERE [ID] = <number>

Comment: I think I did not explain it clearly enough. Let say I want to have another column in my table SaveResponse and I want to get that info based on the ID that is in this User Defined Data type ... from a table called UserTable and column Username .. How would I do that?

Comment: I am not sure about joining criteria, because I don't know Your table structure, but it would be something like : INSERT INTO dbo.SaveResponse(ID, myQuestion, PersonWhoResponses,
                                 Response, [User], [DateTime])

       SELECT 
          A.ID, A.myQuestion, A.PersonWhoResponses,
          A.Response, A.[User], A.[DateTime], B.[ID]
       FROM
          @theDATA AS A JOIN [UserTable] AS B ON A.[User] = B.[UserName]

Comment: Thanks Norbert, I used a function to retrieve my UserName based on user id.. select myUser = dbo.functiongetUsername(ID)  and compared inside the function to match those users are the same. then in the select I added myUser from theData and it worked. I am new here and in comparison you are senior to me in this forum.. so apologize for confusion.. Thanks

Comment: Try : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp and other joins by Yourself